# C# Windows Forms Chart Always Display Zero in YAxis

Tags: c#, winforms, charts

I draw some charts using `DataVisualization.Charting.Chart`. All of my charts have inverse Y range.

For Example "-20 to 20" or "-150 to 150". It means that Zero is always in the middle of Y range, there is no problem in drawing but the chart never makes a label for Zero.

For Example I have this labels `-20,-15,-10,-5,5,10,15,20`. I always want to see the Zero in Y axis labels. See the image:

[image]

Comment: is there any misunderstanding in my question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it using `CustomLabels` :

```
 int maxRange = 20;
 int yInterval = 5;
 var minRange = (maxRange * -1);
 area.AxisY.Minimum = minRange;
 area.AxisY.Maximum = maxRange;
 area.AxisY.LabelStyle.Format = "#";
 area.AxisY.Interval = yInterval;
 int yVal = minRange;
 while (yVal <= maxRange)
 {
    area.AxisY.CustomLabels.Add(yVal - 0.5, yVal + 0.5, yVal.ToString());
    yVal += yInterval;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

for this min & max must in 10s series

```
chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Interval = 10;
chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Interval = 10;
```